# How to disable DMA port in windows 7?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker

I want to use bitlocker.

For security reasons (Direct memory access attacks), I want to disable

- FireWire
- Thunderbolt
- ExpressCard
- PCMCIA
- PCI
- PCI-X
- PCI Express

---

Ref:

- [Types of Attacks for Volume Encryption Keys](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632182.aspx)
- [Blocking the SBP-2 driver and Thunderbolt controllers to reduce 1394 DMA and Thunderbolt DMA threats to BitLocker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2516445)
- Hardware ID

Comment: Some external ones can be disabled in the BIOS, internal ones like PCI can't, and for good reason (if an attacker can access those, he may as well do a cold boot attack or solder wires to the memory modules and read RAM that way)

Comment: This would be better asked in a Windows-specific forum

Comment: I think you are right. Once attackers break into BIOS, they can cold boot attack. BIOS protection is enough. I can't really defend my data in memory even I disable all DMA port. Sadly, it's hard to defend cold boot attack...  Now, this question seems pointless. But it's still nice to know how to disable DMA ports from windows.

Answer (score 0):

PCI, PCI-X, and PCI Express cannot be disabled.  One or more of them will be the main bus the computer uses to communicate with internal peripherals; disabling them is likely to disable your video card, and may disable other things like hard drives, ethernet/wifi, USB, and hard drives/SSD drives, depending on the computer's hardware setup.  There's no security advantage to disabling them, either: since they're internal, an attacker with access to them also has direct physical access to the memory chips, and can simply read them straight rather than going through DMA.

FireWire, Thunderbolt, ExpressCard, and PCMCIA are best disabled through the computer's BIOS.  Your computer's manual might tell you how to access the BIOS; if not, the most common way is to press either `F2` or `DEL` during startup depending on the BIOS.  The layout of the BIOS setting screens varies from computer to computer, so you'll have to consult the manual (or look around for things that look right) to figure out how to disable what you want.  Keep in mind that if you don't know what you're doing, making changes to the BIOS settings can render the computer unusable until you perform a BIOS reset.

If you really want to go through Windows to disable things, Device Manager is the tool you want.  I believe FireWire, Thunderbolt, ExpressCard and PCMCIA all show up under the "System devices" section: to disable one of them, right-click it and select "Properties", then click the "Disable" button on the "Driver" tab.  I've got no idea if this will actually protect you from DMA attacks.

Comment: Which one is ExpressCard? [1](http://i.imgur.com/Z7X4a1q.png) [2](http://i.imgur.com/SpeCvqF.png) [3](http://i.imgur.com/OnJng5o.png)

Comment: I don't know.  I've never encountered a computer with an ExpressCard slot.